# Why would a query return oracle.sql.NUMBER@[hex value] in place of a numeric value?

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I'm seeing some odd behavior in an Oracle 11gR2 database. When I select from a particular table, using SQL Developer, certain rows of the result set include non-numeric results in a `NUMBER` column (with a `NOT NULL` constraint, though I'm not sure that matters). For example:

```
 oracle.sql.NUMBER@b25bc2f
oracle.sql.NUMBER@5a65b760
oracle.sql.NUMBER@4bea2dfd
```

and so on, mixed in with regular numeric values in the same column. When using SQL*Plus I just see blank spaces instead (as with `NULL`), e.g (in the column aliased `COL`):

```
     FYEAR         CO AB  DEV           COL   COUNT(*)
---------- ---------- --- ------ ---------- ----------
      2012          7 SF  107                        1
```

I don't know much about Oracle internals but the strings in SQL Developer look like pointers to me. We stumbled across these not as the result of any error but because a query involving some arithmetic was giving very unexpected results. So, thinking maybe I could dereference them and learn something, I did a bit of experimenting:

- `cast(col as numeric)` always gives 0
- `to_number(col)` throws `ORA-01722: invalid number`
- `col * 1` gives any of an integer, decimal value, `null` or a different `oracle.sql.NUMBER@...`—the results are consistent but *only within a transaction*
- `col * 1 * 1` gives a **different** result than `col * 1`, with no pattern that I can discern (and so for `col * 1 * 1 * 1`, etc.; but `col * 2` is consistent with `col * 1`!)
- when I start a new transaction, in SQL*Plus all the calculated expression results change; in SQL Developer, the the hex values shown change between transactions but the calculated expression results do not! *Wat.*

This is, hands down, the weirdest thing I've ever seen in a database. Is this a sign of corruption in the underlying datafiles? Have I stumbled upon some quirky undefined behavior in Oracle?

Here's an example of the result set changing between transactions—there's only one person with DML rights on this table, I verified he's not working with it, and it has no triggers:

```
Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> select col, cast(col as numeric), col * 1, col * 2, col * 1 * 1, col * 1 * 1 * 1
  2  from schema.table@dblink where foo = bar;

       COL CAST(COLASNUMERIC)      COL*1      COL*2    COL*1*1  COL*1*1*1
---------- ------------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
                            0
                            0        848       1696       9648       1612
                            0       8304       9312                  1612
                            0                                        1612

SQL> rollback;

Rollback complete.

SQL> select col, cast(col as numeric), col * 1, col * 2, col * 1 * 1, col * 1 * 1 * 1
  2  from schema.table@dblink where foo = bar;

       COL CAST(COLASNUMERIC)      COL*1      COL*2    COL*1*1  COL*1*1*1
---------- ------------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
                            0
                            0       8048       6096       3648        140
                            0       8304       9312                   140
                            0                                         140

SQL>
```

In SQL Developer, some of these blanks are `NULL` while others show the `oracle.sql.NUMBER@...` thing, which SQL Developer does *not* treat like a string, even on export:

```
REM INSERTING into EXPORT_TABLE
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (COL,"CAST(COLASNUMERIC)","COL*1","COL*2","COL*1*1","COL*1*1*1") values (oracle.sql.NUMBER@3924c5dc,0,null,null,null,42.939572379395723793957237939572379396);
```

`DUMP()` shows it as a 1-byte numeric; I'm not sure what 193 means as an internal representation. Everything I'm finding so far on Google shows 193 appearing in association with other numbers (e.g., `193,1`) but never by itself; [according to this page](http://www.jlcomp.demon.co.uk/number_format.html), 193 by itself seems nonsensical? Or I'd say it signifies null, except that `DUMP()` shows nulls as `NULL`. In any case, the 193 appears consistently for all of the affected rows:

```
FYEAR   COL                         DUMP(COL)           COL*1
2012    oracle.sql.NUMBER@1ef46be8  Typ=2 Len=1: 193    (null)
2013    oracle.sql.NUMBER@40d85c38  Typ=2 Len=1: 193       112
2014    oracle.sql.NUMBER@3c8e81ca  Typ=2 Len=1: 193       112
2015    oracle.sql.NUMBER@2feb13d5  Typ=2 Len=1: 193      2712
2016    oracle.sql.NUMBER@72631d86  Typ=2 Len=1: 193      2712
...
```

This issue persists if I `CREATE TABLE tbl AS...` with a query on the affected table. I traced it back to a table that is populated via a legacy program written in C, that no-one on staff knows how to decipher. But my assumption is that the C program can't insert anything that violates the `NOT NULL NUMBER` column definition without Oracle kicking it back out with an error (bad assumption?).

Comment: Care to post the table definition (at least the column in question)? Have you tried the [`DUMP()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions046.htm) to see what's stored and what Oracle thinks of the actual data type (for both valid and "invalid" values)?

Comment: It's literally defined as `NUMBER`, with a `NOT NULL` constraint. It's not a key field. I'll look into `DUMP()` and edit with any new information.

Comment: I just noticed that you're looking at the database link, not regular table. What's the data source behind it? I don't know if Oracle stores column definitions for remote tables locally; if so, you may want to check if they remote data type matches what's cached locally.

Comment: The link is to another internal Oracle database, same version and everything; I got the definition info from dictionary views on the link, e.g., `all_tab_columns@dblink`. But it matches a plain `desc` as well.

Comment: Do you get the same result directly from the target database?

Comment: @AndrewBrennan With respect to the values changing in each arithmetic expression, and the underlying bug in our reports, yes; the behavior appears when connected directly or via the link. With respect to whether the item is displayed as an empty space or as `oracle.sql.NUMBER@[hex value]`, it's not clear to me whether the link or the client is the determining factor.

Comment: Anything in V$DATABASE_BLOCK_CORRUPTION? I suspect this is a logical corruption rather than physical, but you should still check.

Comment: try analyzing the table: ANALYZE TABLE xxx VALIDATE STRUCTURE CASCADE;

Comment: @AndrewBrennan Thanks for the suggestions. Analyzing the table reported no errors and the view is empty. Our best guess at this point is that the C program is somehow putting bad data into the table; I just don't understand how, or why Oracle would accept it - not being familiar with OCI (or perhaps there's an older API that's relevant)

Comment: It can't put bad data into the table. Oracle would reject it. The table is most likely logically corrupted.

Comment: `oracle.sql.NUMBER@4bea2dfd` is Java's default way of converting an Object to a "String". Apparently the JDBC driver returns an instance of `oracle.sql.NUMBER` but SQL Developer expects something that can display "itself" using `toString()` - I would try to update the SQL Developer version or at least the JDBC driver version used by SQL Developer

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get completely "invalid" numbers into the database, even using PL/SQL. 
Your guess about 193 is correct, DUMP(X, 1010)

> X = DUMP...
>   -1 = 62,100,102 0 = 128
>   +1 = 193,2
>   +2 = 193,3

My guess is the insertion/update code is using a native programming language type e.g. integer, where as it should be using an Oracle NUMBER type. You can't safely assume an Oracle NUMBER is directly equivalent to C# integer.
Yes I've seen that odd behaviour before SUM/MAX and other numeric functions were not working properly.

Can you identify the code where those 'bad' numbers came from? 
The data those bad numbers represented can never be reconstructed, the best you can hope for is to prevent it from happening again.

Comment: I would have to go back and review this problem but I believe the data may have originated in a particular ~20 year-old Pro*C program, the source code for which I have only as a paper printout about an inch thick. It's something of an office boogeyman to be honest; I may be blaming it unfairly, especially considering the recent comment about about JDBC. don't know if I expect to solve this any time soon.